# Absolute positioning crossfade images inside relative positioned div not working

Tags: css, image, position, css-position

I try to add cross fade images to a page (code taken from here: [cross fade images](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/)
it works but because of the absolute position of the images- img.top and img.bottom (css) it appear behind the text or above it (getting inside another div: about).
when I remove the absolute position, it floats ok near the another text div but the pictures dont cross fade well because they are one near another, and not one on another absolutely.
So using absolute might be a must but I need it to float relative to the other divs and not getting inside them.

someone have an idea how to solve it?

```
<div id="cf">
    <img class="bottom" src="style/images/1.jpg" id="pic1">
    <img class="top" src="style/images/2.jpg" id="pic2">
</div>
<div id="about" class="body_text">
     a lot of text
</div>
```

---

```
and the css:
#cf {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:black;
}
img.top, img.bottom{
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes cf_animation {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    40% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    60% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
#cf img.top {
animation-name: cf_animation;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 8s;
animation-direction: alternate;
}
#about{
position:relative;
    float:top;
}
```

Comment: I hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546288/absolutely-positioning-images-inside-relatively-positioned-div?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I kind had the same problem today and got to a 'solution'. Try this, add another div as a bigger box , and add the same picture there. Then put this div as a relative and put the 'cf' AND the cf img as absolute. Something like this.. I don´t use float so I can´t guarantee it´s gonna work as it did for me..but hope it does.

```
<div id="container">
<img class="bottom" src="style/images/1.jpg" id="pic1">
<div id="cf">
<img class="bottom" src="style/images/1.jpg" id="pic1">
<img class="top" src="style/images/2.jpg" id="pic2">
</div>
</div>

<div id="about" class="body_text">
a lot of text
</div>
```

AND THE CSS

```
#container {
position:relative;}

#cf {
position:absolute;
float:left;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:black;}

img.top, img.bottom{
position:absolute;
width:100px;
height:100px;
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;}
```